# One Hot Encoding From Multiple Rows in R

Tags: r, matrix, machine-learning

Suppose I have data that has the following format:

```
ID VALUE
a  a
a  b
d  b
d  c
```

What I would like to do is a one hot-encoding for the ID value. When I use `model.matrix`, I obtain:

```
model.matrix(~VALUE-1, df)

ID aVALUE bVALUE cVALUE
a  1      0      0
a  0      1      0
d  0      1      0
d  0      0      1
```

What I would like to get however is this:

```
ID aVALUE bVALUE cVALUE
a  1      1      0
d  0      1      1
```

The other part to this is that my data frame is approximately 30 million rows - so I am looking for an efficient way to do this. Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: @Jota - this actually works! Thanks!

Comment: If you want to post it as an answer I will gladly accept it - @Jota

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could  use `table`.

```
d <- table(df$ID, df$VALUE)
#    a b c
#  a 1 2 0
#  d 0 1 1
```

If you have to enforce values of 1 or 0 because some combinations show up more than once, then you can convert those cases to 1:

```
d[d > 1L] <- 1
#    a b c
#  a 1 1 0
#  d 0 1 1
```

Example data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "d", "d"), VALUE = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c")),
   .Names = c("ID", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is `dcast` from `data.table` to convert to 'wide' format from 'long'.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), reshape it to 'wide'format with `dcast` and specify the `fun.aggregate`.  For big datasets, the `dcast` approach would be fast.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), ID~paste0(VALUE, "VALUE"), value.var = "VALUE", 
                function(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0))
#    ID aVALUE bVALUE cVALUE
#1:  a      1      1      0
#2:  d      0      1      1
```

---

Another option is `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   unique() %>%
   mutate(n = 1)%>% 
   spread(VALUE, n, fill = 0)
```