# How to do One-hot encoding with multiple rows for same column_id using Pandas?

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning

I have a df in format:

```
    User_id skill
0   1       python
1   1       java
2   4       java
```

doing

`df=pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['skill'],prefix='skill')],axis=1)
 df`

outputs:

```
   User_id skill_python skill_java
0  1       1            0
1  1       0            1
2  4       0            1
```

I want to get output in format:

```
   User_id skill_python skill_java
0  1       1            1
1  4       0            1
```

How can I do that using pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I one hot encode in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python)

Comment: Those answers don't address case for grouping by a column_id value..I am looking for the python version of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679911/one-hot-encoding-from-multiple-rows-in-r

Comment: Side note: once you have more than one "hot" line you no longer have "_one hot_ encoding".

Answer (score 1):

Answered here:

Basically, declare index, and pivot table.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8253/how-to-binary-encode-multi-valued-categorical-variable-from-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Just group by Id with aggregation - 'max' after one-hot encoding.